# creating columns within a legend list while using ggplot in R code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting 15 lines using `ggplot` (package name: ggplot2), each representing a separate entity and wish to create a legend for the same. However, I am not able to divide the legend entries into more than one column. Can someone please suggest how to do the same in ggplot environment.

Presently, I am using the following command to create legend:

```
opts(title=plotName,legend.position='bottom')
```

However, this gives a one column legend. As a result a large area in the chart is taken by legend itself. Dividing it into 2 or 3 columns would really help the cause while keeping the legend at the bottom of the chart. 
I also tried `legend.direction` but this command displays legend in one row which is not desirable either unless I may spread it across 2-3 rows.

```
opts(title=plotName,legend.position='bottom',legend.direction="horizontal")
```

Thanks in advance,
Munish

Answer (score 11):

Using the new themes environment of ggplot requires only a simple: `+ guides(col=guide_legend(ncol=2))` to format your legend in 2 columns.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `guide_legend()` to control the layout and appearance of ggplot legends. In particular, it takes arguments `nrow` and `ncol`, which are what you're after.

Here's an example taken from Section 2 of the very helpful document  [Changes and additions to ggplot2-0.9.0.pdf](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf).

```
library(ggplot2)

q <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = table, fill = clarity)) +
     geom_histogram() +
     scale_y_continuous()

q + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, title.hjust = 0.4,
        title.theme = theme_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))) +
xlim(45, 75)
```

Comment: The link is no more available. Any clue, where can I get the similar article?

Comment: @classy_BLINK Googling the name of the doc, I found a copy [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjm-LrJ26r1AhV2LTQIHWFqCDMQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2F05154779709936255585.googlegroups.com%2Fattach%2F7512af8ea3504b17%2Fggplot2-0.9.0-BW.pdf).